# Is it possible to upload a video while still letting the user interact with app?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS's transferUtility.uploadData which uses the background transfer feature in iOS to upload videos

Basically when a user presses a button to start transferUtility.uploadData, a new screen is pushed on the navigationController. So while the video is uploading, they can interact with the new screen.

The problem is there a huge delay when the screen is pushed on the navigation, and I was wondering if there was a way to push a screen on the navigationController (like instagram after taking a video a new screen appears to customize or send to friends) instantly.

```
 transferUtility.uploadData(
        data,
        bucket: S3BucketName,
        key: videoName,
        contentType: "movie/mov",
        expression: expression,
        completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith { (task) -> AnyObject! in
            if let error = task.error {
                print(error)
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

            if let _ = task.result {
                print("Upload Starting!----")

                // Do something with uploadTask.

                //Open new screen
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(CameraDetailTableViewController(videoURL: AWS_URL + videoName), animated: false)


            }

            return nil;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either use Grand Central Dispatch or AWSExecutor.

See the documentation for AWSTask for full details on how to implement.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/awstask.html

Answer (score 0):

Use dispatch_async to upload y our video. That way the upload is on a different thread in the app and will run in the background, thus the user can work fine. In the completion handler of the upload you can then notify the user via popup that the upload succeeded.

Here is the code for dispatch async:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { // in half a second...
    //upload your video here
}
```